# exchange server with different domain name

Tags: exchange

We have a Domain Controller with the name of *example.com* (unregistered  domain name), all hosts connected to domain and I want to bring up a exchange server.

This exchange server is a member of *example.com* and I have a public domain name *abc.com*.

What I want: if any one (in local or public) sends an email the address format should be like `user1@abc.com` not like `user1@example.com`.

Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: You'll need to configure your E-Mail Address Policy and your Accepted Domains in order to send/receive email from/for the domain name in question.

Comment: I haven't been touching Exchange for years, but below is what I remember: Externally, you need to have a public IP for your mail server, and an MX record pointing to your public IP. On exchange server, you need to set up receipient policy (how they call back in exchange 2003, not sure which component is responsble for stamping addresses now) and a connector. Anyway, these are very basic Exchange admin questions, a good read of Exchange documents is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know which version of exchange you are using but to do this in Exchange 2013 you need to do the following.

- Login into the Exchange Admin Center
- Go to Mailflow
- Select Accepted Domains
- Add a new Authority Domain, with your external Domain name
- Then select Email Address Policy, Create a new policy that creates an email address with that new domain.

You will need to ensure that your send connector is configured as well as your receive connector.

MX Records will need to be configured with your domain name pointing to your public ip address, also if you want to be able to send from Exchange directly you would need to ensure that a rDNS/Pointer record is applied to your public ip address with your ISP.